# Before or after when adding to sets in C++

Tags: c++, performance, stdvector

Given

```
my_type m;
std::vector<my_type> v;
```

Which runs more quickly?

```
m.generate_data_inside_self();
v.push_back(m);
```

Or

```
v.push_back(m);
v[0].generate_data_inside_self();
```

If the vector held pointers to the my_types then both would seem about the same.

However when copying in the whole my_type object as in this example I think the 2nd would be faster as there is less to copy as the extra data only comes into existance after "m" is inside "v".

edit:

In the example in my program my_type looks sort of like this.

```
my_type
{
    private:
        std::vector<unsigned short> data; //empty after construction

    public:
        //no destructors, assignment operators
        //copy constructors etc... explicitly (are) defined
        generate_data_inside_self() //populates data
        {
            //contains for example a loop that populates
            //"data" with some (lets say 50) values
        }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't the constructor generating the data? Objects that require the user to call some member function to be usable suck. Be usable after construction, always.

Comment: You'r wild generalisation is almost certainly wrong sometimes. Besides which my_type would then suck as an example for this question.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Got carried away. But you see what I was trying to say there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it when the complexity of copy constructor/operator == is smaller. If you are generating data, most likely increasing that complexity, insert before generating.

If you have many vector copies and you are concerned about performance, my suggestion is to have a `vector` of pointers and `new` (and of course one day `delete`) the objects and put them in the `vector`. That way, the cost of inserting in `vector` is not dependent on the complexity of the object.

Comment: I think insert before generating is probbably the case as well, would be nice to get some more varification either way before accepting an answer, there seems to be a fair amount of disagreement and people not having read the last part of the question.

Comment: What kind of verification do you mean? Isn't it clear how when a class gets mode data, copying it would take more time?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but it depends too much on what your type is. If it holds pointers to some big external block of data, copying it might take essentially no time at all, but you could find that copying it after generating the data is massively slow. Only you know, and if you care about the performance, the only way to find out is to whack it in a `for` loop and time it.

Comment: Thanks. I've just added more information to the question to allow for a more precise answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you worry about performance here, don't use `std::vector<my_type>`. Vector will copy all elements on every memory reallocation and can copy elements on element erasure from vector. Use `boost::ptr_vector` or `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr>`, this improves performance in both cases: adding elements to vector and reallocation/erasure.

**EDIT:**

I revised my answer:

The second approach has better performance because avoids copying of *filled* `my_type` instance (as opposite to default-constructed with empty `std::vector` member) on adding to vector. But it's less readable and less *canonical*. I would recommend to use the first approach as default one and only after profiling to selectively use the second approach or as - I previously proposed - to use `boost::ptr_vector` or `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr>`

Comment: The performance of `std::vector` is amortized O(1). In fact, instead of cost `1` per add, the cost is only `2`. It's pretty good.

Comment: ty for the helpfull information. I've vote upped your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you give us more data, I think this **depends** on what your class contains and what data it has to generate.  It's rather hard to tell which will be faster, as there could be things involved we cannot tell from  your question.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on exactly how the type is defined, and what the function you call does.

In both cases, the object `m` is copied into the vector after being constructed.

So the answer depends on whether `generate_data_inside_self` makes a copy more expensive or not. And that depends on how the assignment operator is defined. (And whether, in C++11, a move assignment operator exists, and whether you allow it to be called.)

But as always with performance questions, the only answer that matters is the one you get when you run the code. If you want to know which is faster, time the code and see for yourself.

Comment: Given my example code showing how my_type is defined at the bottom of my question, whats the answer? :¬P

Comment: You haven't shown the full definition of the type. What does its assignment (and move assignment) operator look like? Does it have any other data members? (And why don't you simply benchmark it?)

Comment: It's assignment and move assignment operator are not defined (they are as default), it's other properties are not relevent to the question, i'd end up having to describe a lot more of the program it's a part of, also the answer won't help others much if it's too specific. It would be helpfull to know more than just how fast it will run on my system, I didn't realise it would be such a complicated question to answer or that the C++ verstion would play a signifegent role.

Comment: I've further clarified the question.

Answer (score -1):

The size of `m` is fixed in both examples.  Any data you generate in `generate_data_inside_self()` is either just filling in holes or allocating space that `vector` doesn't care about (i.e. on the heap).

And more to the point, the content of that data is opaque from `vector`'s perspective, so it doesn't effect performance if it happens to be all zeroes or a random assortment of values; the whole block of size `sizeof(m)` is copied either way.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, this would suggest that internally "data" in "my_type" (see the extra information I added to my question) is a sort of pointer and copying a my_type doesn't actually copy it's "data" attribute just a refrance to it. Can you look at the example I've provided and clarify i've understood this correctly.

Comment: `sizeof(m)` might not change, but the complexity of `m`'s copy constructor/assignment operator certainly can change.  `vector` does not just blindly copy chunks of memory.