# Which C++ object copies more quickly?

Tags: c++, performance, stdvector

Two instances of this C++ object exist.

```
my_type
{
    public:
        std::vector<unsigned short> a;
}
```

One where the std::vector is empty and the other where it contains 50 elements.

Which instance copies most quickly or do they copy in the same time?

Comment: I've edited in a clarification.

Comment: I can't even begin to imagine why the answer to this question should not be obvious.

Comment: Trying to break down this question to get a decent answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457747/before-or-after-when-adding-to-sets-in-c/7457955#7457955

Comment: After reading that one: if your program runs slowly, it does so because it has bigger problems than the order of the populate/push operations. Step back from the details because you are not going to cure the disease by treating the symptoms.

Comment: It's not running slowly, it's very efficient, and obviously there is a simpler to think about solution but I'm still wondering if the other way will work as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a `std::vector` is copied all of it's elements are also copied - so the time taken should be proportional to `vector.size()`.

In `c++0x` so called *move* semantics are introduced, allowing a move constructor and move assignment operator to be defined for types. These *are* defined for standard library containers (such as `std::vector`) and should allow for vector's to be moved in `O(1)` time. If you're worried about performance, maybe you could re-cast your operations to make use of these new features.

EDIT: Based on the linked question, if you're worried about the extra copies potentially done when calling `vector::push_back` you have a few options:

1. In `c++0x` use the new `vector::emplace_back` instead. This allows for your objects to be constructed *in-place* in the container.
2. In `c++0x` use *move* semantics, via something like `vector.push_back(std::move(object_to_push))`. For POD types this will still do more copying than the `emplace_back` option.
3. Store a container of pointers to objects rather than objects themselves. The only thing that will get copied by the container in this case is the pointer itself - which is cheap. You potentially want to use some variant of smart pointers with this option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah it does, it's refreshing to see a good, straight answer, even more so to see one quickly :¬)